# Eigenvalues/Eigenvectors for Matrices Question - Deriving Relations?

Tags: matrices, ordinary-differential-equations

What I'm struggling with is this question out of a Differential Equations text:

To obtain a second linearly independent solution to $x' = Ax$ try $x_2(t)=te^{-t}u_1 + e^{-t}u_2 $.

Hint: Substitute $x_2$ into the system $x' = Ax$ and derive the relations:

$(A + I)u_1 = 0$

$(A + I)u_2 = u_1$

So I've gotten to this point, which is in line with a worked solution I found:

$Ate^{-t}u_1 + Ae^{-t}u_2 = -te^{-t}u_1 + e^{-t}u_1 - e^{-t}u_2  $

Solution then says "collecting like terms, we get the two relations", but I'm struggling to actually do this. It's not necessarily important to know how to derive these relations to obtain the "answer" to the problem given, but I'd like to know how to do it for its own sake. Can anyone help?

Also - just to avoid any possible confusion, I in the above relations is a diagonal 1 matrix like 
$$
        \begin{bmatrix}
        1 & 0   \\
        0 & 1   
         \end{bmatrix}
$$

Thanks in advance.

Edit - If you guys want A, A is

$$
        \begin{bmatrix}
        1 & -1 \\
        4 & -3 
        \end{bmatrix}
$$

Edit 2 - Also if it's any help the exact words of the solution I found say: "On equating the coefficents of like terms" we get the relations.

If anyone wants to view the solution in its entirety its here - http://www.slader.com/textbook/9780321747747-fundamentals-of-differential-equations-and-boundary-value-problems-sixth-edition/535/exercises/35/

I'm confused on how to derive the relations in part c, which this solution skips over. The rest I understand.

Comment: I personally don't think it's needed to find the relations, but sure -

Comment: Sorry, hit enter one too many times. A is


A = $$
        \begin{matrix}
        1 & -1  \\
        4 &  -3  \\
        \end{matrix}
$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, as a side comment, the matrix is kinda important, because this form for a particular second solution isn't always true — that depends on the matrix. But on the other hand, it will only come into play when solving those two relations, while your question is how they were obtained.

The hint "collecting like terms, we get the two relations" probably means the following: in the equation that you already (correctly!) obtained, collect the terms with $te^{-t}$ and with $e^{-t}$. More specifically:
$$Ate^{−t}u_1+Ae^{−t}u_2=−te^{−t}u_1+e^{−t}u_1−e^{−t}u_2$$
$$Ate^{−t}u_1+Ae^{−t}u_2+te^{−t}u_1-e^{−t}u_1+e^{−t}u_2=0$$
$$(Ate^{−t}u_1+te^{−t}u_1)+(Ae^{−t}u_2-e^{−t}u_1+e^{−t}u_2)=0$$
$$(Au_1+u_1)te^{−t}+(Au_2-u_1+u_2)e^{−t}=0$$
So that this is identically equal to zero for all $t$, both "coefficients" have to be zero. Thus we conclude that:
$$Au_1+u_1=0 \quad \Rightarrow \quad (A+I)u_1=0$$
$$Au_2-u_1+u_2=0 \quad \Rightarrow \quad (A+I)u_2=u_1$$

Comment: Makes perfect sense now, thank you!